# SharePoint REST getting error 404

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

When I open browser with URL bellow, it throws error **404 (Not Found)**:

```
http://app-xxxxxxxxx.win-xxxxxxx:47699/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('RESTList2')/items
-1, System.ArgumentException List 'RESTList2' does not exist at site with URL 'http://app-08cf359d3cc937.win-85bfgfhvfnu:47699'.
```

I can view the list at this URL:

```
http://app-xxxxxxxxx.win-xxxxxxxx:47699/SharePointAddIn1/Lists/RESTList2/AllItems.aspx
```

Please help. I am stuck here for long time.

```
// Load the required SharePoint libraries.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get the URI decoded URLs.
    hostweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
        );

    // The js files are in a URL in the form:
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource_file
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to
    // the execOperation function.
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", Jsom_AddItem);
        }
    );

    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", Jsom_LoadCamel);
        }
    );
});


function CreateListItemREST() {
    var listName = "RESTList2";
    var newItemTitle = "New Title Item";
    CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, newItemTitle, function () {
        alert("New Item has been created successfully.");
    }, function () {
        alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again.");
    });
}

// CREATE Operation
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// weburl: The url of the web that the list is in. 
// newItemTitle: New Item title.
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItemTitle, success, failure) {

    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": newItemTitle
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}

// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Comment: What is the display name of your list(Not the name in the url of list)?? in `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle()` endpoint, you need to provide the display name of list.

Comment: Are you sure that list with title **RESTList2** exists? You are using funtion ``getByTitle()`` so it looks for list by title, not url. Try to load all lists ``/_api/web/lists?$select=Title``·and see if you can find **RESTList2**.

Comment: The display name of list "RESTList2" . And can be accessed from the url (can view) http://app-xxxxxxxxx.win-xxxxxxxx:47699/SharePointAddIn1/Lists/RESTList2/AllItems.aspx

Comment: when I am trying to find the list using "_api/web/lists/?$select=Title"  my list not showing their . 

But can be accessible from  (Can add / edit /view item in list )

URL - http://app-xxxxxxxxxx.win-xxxxxxxx:47699/SharePointAddIn1/Lists/RESTList2/AllItems.aspx

Comment: I just noticed that you are accessing wrong URL. It is missing the ``SharePointAddIn1`` part. It should be ``http://app-xxxxxxxxx.win-xxxxxxx:47699/SharePointAddIn1/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('RESTList2')/items``. ``_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`` will give you only the root url without ``SharePointAddIn1`` so you should use ``_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas Nespor . You are correct . Now error message got changed . Have a good day .

Thank you all for helping me up .

Comment: @BISWANATHHALDER I posted it as answer, please mark is as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing wrong URL. It is missing the **SharePointAddIn1** part. It should be:

```
http://app-xxxxxxxxx.win-xxxxxxx:47699/SharePointAddIn1/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('RESTList2')/items.
```

`_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` will give you only the root url (site collection) without **SharePointAddIn1** so you should use `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` instead.

Comment: http://app-xxxxxxx.win-xxxxxxxx:47699/SharePointAddIn1/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RESTList2')/items 



Now getting @message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The type SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not suppot

Comment: Remove the `X-HTTP-Method` header if you are creating new item. It should be used only for updates of existing item. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface